# SQL for locating a date range using a date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

Ok, so this is a little confusing (hence why I am asking for help)

I have a table in a MySQL database that looks like so:

```
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id  | supplier_id | start_date | end_date   | days_attended | user_id | client_id | trashed |
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
|   1 |          15 | 1410098400 | 1410703200 |             2 |       7 |       424 |       0 |
|   2 |          84 | 1411912800 | 1420117200 |             3 |       7 |       395 |       0 |
|   3 |         183 | 1390827600 | 1418907600 |             2 |       7 |        96 |       0 |
|   4 |          85 | 1412431200 | 1419512400 |             5 |       7 |       105 |       0 |
|   5 |         168 | 1411912800 | 1412258400 |             3 |       7 |        53 |       0 |
```

My dilemma is that I want to create a report from this table that takes a date range as input and the returns a list of dates from within that date range.

As you can see there is a start and end date for each row. So I need a SQL query that will search for a date within these two dates PER ROW using the two dates selected by the user.

i.e. User selects date range: 21/09/2015 to 21/12/2015. Then the query will look for dates between these dates by using the existing date range in the table.

Comment: how to handle the overlaped range? not completely included in the use sepecified range

Comment: Do you want both the start date and end date given in the table to be between the two dates specified by the user?

Comment: Both dates in the table do not need to be within the specified dates. just as long as one is or any date between the table dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if either the start_date or end_date is between the user's start date and end date.

You could plug the users values in for the **user_start_date** and **user_end_date** here:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (start_date >= user_start_date AND start_date <= user_end_date) 
OR (end_date >= user_start_date AND end_date <= user_end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (
start_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(var_date_1, '%d/%M/%Y')) AND 
end_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(var_date_2, '%d/%M/%Y'))
) ;
```